# Get SPListItem by title is very slow

Tags: 2010, caml-query, splistitem, caml

I want to get a SPListItem by title. I´m using a CAML query to filter the list (Around 1000 items). There is only 1 item with the title in the list.

My problem is now that the performance is really bad. I think the performance problem occur at `items[0]`. And sure the problem is only in the production environment not in my development environment.

Is there a performance bottleneck in my code?

[image]

Comment: Add an index to that column.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! I´m already thinking about to index the column...